# Adding Shadows at the bottom of a container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, shadow, box-shadow

I have a simple screen with a container about 100 in height and with blue color.  I want to add a shadow or elevation at the bottom of the container.

This is my code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/strings.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/dimens.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/colors.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new IncomeFragment());
}

class IncomeFragment extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: margin_100dp,
            color: colorPrimary,

          ),
          new Container(    //container to  overlay on top of blue container
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,


            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[

                Text(
                    zero_amount,
                    style: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 40.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

can someone help me to add a shadow or elevation at the bottom of my blue container?

see image below.  shawdow should be in place in the red circle
[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can reuse the first container that you have in your Stack, the container has a property called decoration and it accept a widget of kind BoxDecoration, as you can see in this link: [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)
Inside this widget you can use the boxShadow property to give to your container a custom shadow, try the next code:

```
new Container(
      height: margin_100dp,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black54,
                blurRadius: 15.0,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
            )
          ],
        color: colorPrimary
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: also you use card widget

Comment: It gives me very weird output. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

Or you can wrap your Container widget with a Material widget which contains an elevation property to give the shadowy effects.

```
Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                elevation: 15.0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(child: Text("Material",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 100,),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          blurRadius: 15.0,
                          offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
                      )
                    ],
                    color: Colors.blue
                ),
                child: Center(child: Text('Box Shadow',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

### Image:

[image]

Difference between two widgets is shown above. Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 24):

Yes, BoxShadow can solve the problem but instead of manually adding the list of BoxShadow, there is a handy map in flutter call ***kElevationToShadow*** which map elevation keys to pre-defined list of BoxShadow. It is also defined based on the [material design elevation](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html).

```dart
Container(
  height: 60.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[4],
    color: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
  ),
  child: ...
);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Colors.white,
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[2], // Use This kElevationToShadow ***********
   ),
   child: Center(child: Text('With BoxShadow')),
),
```

[image]

```
Material( // Using Material Widget ***********************
  elevation: 5,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    child: Center(child: Text('With BoxShadow')),
 ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use the Container Shadow as below:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        offset: Offset(20.0, 10.0),
        blurRadius: 20.0,
        spreadRadius: 40.0,
      ),
    ], 
  ),
```

Controll the blurRadius and the SpreadRadius depending on your needs

Answer (score 3):

if you want a container to have shadow only top

```
 boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 218, 218),
        blurRadius: 10.0, // soften the shadow
        spreadRadius: 0.0, //extend the shadow
        offset: Offset(
          0.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
          -15.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
        ),
      )
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add several BoxShadow to show the shadow you need,
with OffSet propertie you can move the shadow.

```
boxShadow: [
             BoxShadow(
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 offset: Offset(0, 8), // hide shadow top
                 blurRadius: 5),
             BoxShadow(
               color: Colors.white,  // replace with color of container
               offset: Offset(-8, 0), // hide shadow right
             ),
             BoxShadow(
               color: Colors.white, // replace with color of container
               offset: Offset(8, 0), // hide shadow left
             ),
           ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.6),
                      blurRadius: 12.0,
                      spreadRadius: 6.0,
                      offset: Offset(
                        0,
                        10,
                      )),
```