# flutter only bottom shadow to container

Tags: flutter, shadow, flutter-container

i have tried many solution but i couldn't get what i want.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744034/4862911 i applied in this answer but couldn't get correct response. There is still shadow top of container. How can i achieve it?

and also i have tried to surround my widget with `Material` . but still can't solve the problem.

```
 Material(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: _buildEloAndLevel(),

        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Material(
  elevation: 5,
  child: Container(
    height: 50,
    child: _buildEloAndLevel(),

    // add boxShadow
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        color: Colors.black54,
        blurRadius: 15.0,
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

This will create a `shadow` of `15 units` arounds the `Container`. Now, the shadow can be moved with the `offset` property. Since, we don't want shadow on top, we can move it down by `15 units`.

```
Material(
  elevation: 5,
  child: Container(
    height: 50,
    child: _buildEloAndLevel(),

    // add boxShadow
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        color: Colors.black54,
        blurRadius: 15.0,
        offset: Offset(0, 15), // horizontally move 0, vertically move 15,
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if other examples are really setting a shadow for only bottom, but here is a know solution:

```dart
Container(
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  blurRadius: 20.0,
                  spreadRadius: -20.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 25.0),
                )
              ],
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
```

Set the blur of the shadow with `blurRadius` and then set the `spreadRadius` to negative the `blurRadius` then use the `dy` property of the `Offset()` constructor, you set it to positive values to control the shadow bottom.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is playing around with your offset's value. And I think you don't need to wrap it with `Material`.

Offset is the displacement of the shadow from the box. It requires 2 double-types values, `Offset(x, y);`

Example:

```
Container(
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  offset: Offset(15.0, 20.0),
                  blurRadius: 20.0,
                )
              ],
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
```

**TIPS FROM ME:** To make sure the shadow doesn't show up in the top of your container, make sure your blur radius *is not bigger* than your Offset's y-value.